# How to assign or declare variable in target specific?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How to assign or declare variable in target specific?

Here i had try this example.

```
foo = welcome

all: foo = hello
    echo $(foo)
```

But i get commands commence before first target.  Stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a target-specific assignment and a rule definition at the same time.  You have to separate them:

```
all: foo = hello
all:
         echo $(foo)
```

Your version creates a target `all` which has three prerequisites: `foo`, `=`, and `hello`.